# C# LINQ 'GroupBy' operator usage

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

In c#, after enumerating through a collection of 'TeamFixtureResultPage' types i am using the LINQ operator 'GroupBy' to group the items by month using the dateTime value set on the instance. As expected, when its finished processing this returns an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TeamFixtureResultPage>>`

I would like to have the option of ordering the sorted months and the sorted team fixture result page types either ascending or descending. To achieve this at the moment i have the following code which despite producing the output i desire, it all feels a bit clunky and feels like i'm going against the DRY principles? There is probably better ways to achieve this too.

```
       IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, TeamFixtureResultPage>> groupedFixResList = null;

        if (teamFixResLandingPage.FixturesDisplay == "descending")
        {
            groupedFixResList = seasonLandingPage
                .Children<TeamFixtureResultPage>()
                .OrderByDescending(x => x.KickOffTime)
                .GroupBy(x => x.KickOffTime.Month)
                .OrderBy(group => group.Key)
                .Reverse();

            //example output (descending)

            //MAY
            // -Fixture 1 20/05/2020
            // -Fixture 2 15/05/2020
            // -Fixture 3 10/05/2020

            //APRIL
            // -Fixture 1 27/04/2020
            // -Fixture 2 18/04/2020
            // -Fixture 3 13/04/2020
        }
        else
        {
            groupedFixResList = seasonLandingPage
                .Children<TeamFixtureResultPage>()
                .OrderBy(x => x.KickOffTime)
                .GroupBy(x => x.KickOffTime.Month)
                .OrderBy(group => group.Key);

            //example output (ascending)

            //APRIL
            // -Fixture 3 13/04/2020
            // -Fixture 2 18/04/2020
            // -Fixture 1 27/04/2020

            //MAY
            // -Fixture 3 10/05/2020
            // -Fixture 2 15/05/2020
            // -Fixture 1 20/05/2020
        }
```

I have a couple of questions at this point.

Q1. Is it possible to trim this down as i'm effectively calling the following twice

```
groupedFixResList = seasonLandingPage
                    .Children<TeamFixtureResultPage>()
```

Q2. The TeamFixtureResultPage has a lot more properties than what i actually need to pass to the view so is there anyway i can create a new object all within the same LINQ statement e.g. add the following in a .Select somewhere ?

```
    var fixtureResult = new fixtureResult() 
    {        
       Scoreline = x.scoreline,
       FixtureDate = x.fixtureDate    
    }
```

I could do the following after the LINQ statements

```
var newGroupedFixResList = new List<FixtureResult>();

foreach (var group in groupedFixResList)
{
     foreach (var item in group)
     {
        var fixRes = new FixtureResult()
         {                 
              //map properties
         }

         newGroupedFixResList.Add(fixRes);

     }                        
 }
```

I have this working and may be overthinking this? Can anyone offer any advice please?

Thank you

Comment: No need to do the ordering before the grouping, do the ordering conditionally at the end, after the grouping.

Comment: Hi Oliver, perhaps i was doing this wrong but i found that when i wasn't applying the ordering before the groupby the child items were not in order for descending. Can you elaborate please? Thanks

Comment: I mean you can perform the ordering at the end, if you project out into your desired type, you can order the inner collection at that point based on the selected ordering type - no need to do it before the `GroupBy`.

Comment: why do `OrderBy` and then `Reverse` instead of one `OrderByDescending`?

Comment: Hey @Evyatar, I'm unsure, i was trying lots of things at the time and left it in. I've updated to OrderBYDescending as this makes sense. Thanks for pointing this out

Answer (score 1):

you can use 1\-1 as multiplier that chooses the ordering direction, like so:

```
bool reverseOrder = teamFixResLandingPage.FixturesDisplay == "descending";
int orderSign = reverseOrder ? -1 : 1;
groupedFixResList = seasonLandingPage
                .Children<TeamFixtureResultPage>()
                .OrderBy(x => orderSign  * x.KickOffTime.Ticks)
                .GroupBy(x => x.KickOffTime.Month)
                .OrderBy(group => orderSign * group.Key)
```

I won't say it's pretty, but that's one way to do that in a single statement without code duplication.